# what's an elegant method to transfer/cast a poco of 1 type to a poco of another type - different namespace but same name and fields?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say you have a Domain layer which returns a User object:

```
public class User
{
   public string FirstName{get;set;}
   public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

Let's say you have an identical class defined in your service layer. What's an elegant method to easily transfer/cast the Domain User object into a service User object?

Answer (score 1):

"Elegant" is subjective. I might just write an extension that converts one to the other.

```
public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public ThisNameSpace.User ToThisUser(this OtherNameSpace.User source)
    {
        return new ThisNameSpace.User
        {
            FirstName = source.FirstName,
            LastName = source.LastName,
            UserId = source.UserId
        }
    }
}
```

To me that's the simplest.

You could also use Automapper (add from Nuget.)

Do a one-time configuration:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(c=>c.CreateMap<User,Other.User>());
```

and then you can call it to map an instance of `User` to a new instance of `Other.User`.

```
var other = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Other.User>(user);
```

It works without specifying the mapping for individual properties if the property names and types are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace First
{
    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public User()
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace Second
{
    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public User()
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace YetAnotherNamespace
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            First.User user = new First.User()
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Public",
                UserID = "jpublic@mydomain.com"
            };

            Second.User newUser = ConvertUser(user);

        }

        public Second.User ConvertUser(First.User oldUser)
        {
            Second.User newUser = new Second.User();

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in oldUser.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                string propertyName = prop.Name;
                object propertyValue = prop.GetValue(oldUser);
                newUser.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(newUser, propertyValue);
            }

            return newUser;
        }
    }
}
```

In this code sample, when I instantiate the form, I create a First.User and convert it to a Second.User.

This is tested and working (as a strongly-typed method).  I think you can make it more generic and accept and return an "object", and it will just throw an exception if the properties don't match up.  Also keep in mind that reflection tends to be slow - this may not be the most scalable solution.

Another approach would be serializing to json and then deserializing to the other type.

Comment: @pete - I like the serialize/deserialize approach.  How's the performance with this?

Comment: @JimPlatts - I just tested side by side - the Json method took 0.11 seconds, and the reflection method took 0.0008 seconds, so using Json.Net took 147 times as long to get the same result (although depending on the application, 0.11 seconds might be perfectly acceptable if you aren't doing it in a big loop...)

Comment: @JimPlatts - I'm fairly certain that Json.Net uses quite a bit of reflection behind the scenes, so any performance issues caused by reflection will show up both places. ScottHannen's approach is likely to be the fastest approach, but will require a lot more code for a non-trivial object (with more than a few properties to hand code)